# CSS Slide Show only working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser

I'm re-designing a website and cannot use Jquery to create a slide show.

I found a CSS version of a slide show and modified it to work the way I preferred.

I can now only view the slide show in Internet Explorer, it will not work in any other browser that I have tested. I thought I used the correct prefix but maybe I don't understand these as well as i thought.

I'd like it to work in all relevant modern browsers.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dshojaei/x3uxkxx0/)

```css
.css-slideshow{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 697px;
    height: 288px;
    margin-top:300px;
}
.css-slideshow figure{
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 697px;
    height: 288px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
}
.css-slideshow img{
    box-shadow:;
}
.css-slideshow figcaption{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .3);
    font-size: .8em;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}

.css-slideshow-attr{
    max-width: 697px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: .7em;
    font-style: italic;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.css-slideshow-attr a{
    color: #666;
}
.css-slideshow figure{
    opacity:0;
}
figure:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 42s infinite;
    animation: xfade 48s 42s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
    animation: xfade 48s 36s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 30s infinite;
    animation: xfade 48s 30s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
    animation: xfade 48s 24s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 18s infinite;
    animation: xfade 48s 18s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
    animation: xfade 48s 12s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 6s infinite;
    animation: xfade 48s 6s infinite;
}
figure:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
    animation: xfade 48s 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes xfade{
    0%{
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    10.5% {
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    12.5%{
        opacity: 0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    }
    98% {
        opacity: 0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    }
    100% {
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="css-slideshow">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/review_slide/test_slide1.jpg" alt="class-header-css3" width="697" height="288" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-172" /><figcaption><strong>CSS3:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/review_slide/test_slide2.jpg" alt="class-header-semantics" width="697" height="288" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-179" /><figcaption><strong>Semantics:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/review_slide/test_slide3.jpg" alt="class-header-offline" width="697" height="288" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-178" /><figcaption><strong>Offline &amp; Storage:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/review_slide/test_slide1.jpg" alt="class-header-device" width="697" height="288" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-177" /><figcaption><strong>Device Access:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/review_slide/test_slide2.jpg" alt="class-header-connectivity" width="697" height="288" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-176" /><figcaption><strong>Connectivity:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/review_slide/test_slide3.jpg" alt="class-header-multimedia" width="697" height="288" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-175" /><figcaption><strong>Multimedia:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/review_slide/test_slide1.jpg" alt="class-header-3d" width="697" height="288" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-174" /><figcaption><strong>3D, Graphics &amp; Effects:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.offsetprinting.com/img/custom_images/review_slide/test_slide2.jpg" alt="class-header-performance" width="697" height="288" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-173" /><figcaption><strong>Performance &amp; Integration:</strong></figcaption> 
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me in Chrome.

Comment: How about Firefox, Safari? I can only see it on Internet Explore, and the same for my Mac.

Comment: Looks identical to me in Chrome 43, Internet Explorer 11, and Firefox 36.

Comment: what version of IE are you using? you could be using a version that is not properly supported by the code

Comment: It's the newest version of IE. So you guys can see it in all the browsers? I'm not seeing it in Firefox, and Safari now....  As in unmodified to you mean no pre-fix?

Comment: So i restarted my computer today after it froze on me. Oddly enough i can now see it in all the browsers except Safari... Seems as if the browsers are turning on me.